# Excel: calculate percentage values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've these values in an Excel table

```
product component   value
 alpha    a1          0
 alpha    a2          1
 beta     b1          0
 beta     b2          0
 beta     b3          1
 delta    d1          1
 delta    d2          1
```

and I need to calculate the percentage of '0' values in the 'component' field for each unique value in the 'product' field.

For example, based on the sample data, I expect the value '50%' for the 'alpha' product, '67%' for the 'beta' product, and '0%' for the 'delta' product.

Is there any formula (or combination of formulas) in Excel to achieve this result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `COUNTIFS()` function.

```
 =COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$8,E2,$C$2:$C$8,0)/COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$8,E2)
```

All in one formula-

```
=LET(x,UNIQUE(A2:A8),y,COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$8,x,$C$2:$C$8,0)/COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$8,x),HSTACK(x,y))
```

***Please Note:*** You must format the cell as `Percentage` to show result as `%`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can extract unique values from your list with:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(COUNTIF(D$1:D1,$A$2:$A$8)=0),$A$2:$A$8)
```

Where:

- D$1:D1 is one cell above where you want to start the unique values list
- $A$2:$A$8 is your actual data source

Check this article: https://www.spreadsheetweb.com/get-unique-items-from-list/

Then you can achieve what you need with COUNTIFS

```
=COUNTIF($A$2:$A$8,D2)
```

This will give you how many times a product exists in your list. I'll call it: **A**

```
=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$8,D2,$C$2:$C$8,0)
```

Lets you count by multiple criterias, in this case, how many of the product has a value = 0. I'll call it: **B**

Now you can just divide B/A and you'll get the percentage.

This would give you the same answer in a single line:

```
= (  COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$8,D3,$C$2:$C$8,0) / COUNTIF($A$2:$A$8,D3) )
```

To help you visualize what is happening:

[image]